# changing speed of song while its playing and have the changed effects in the song using python

Tags: python, multithreading, pydub

i want to change the tempo of music that is playing and reflect it into the currently playing song so if i want i can change the tempo while the song is playing.

```
from pydub import *
from pydub.playback import play

sound = AudioSegment.from_wav('mymusic.wav')

newsound = sound.speedup(playback_speed=2)
play(newsound)`
```

this code doesn't let me interfere with the music playing it does the job after the music is played completely and i want to interfere with the music playing currently and have the changed tempo as the music plays along

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code, the explanations are in the comments:

```py
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import _play_with_sounddevice

sound = AudioSegment.from_wav("mymusic.wav")

# Set the initial tempo change factor.
tempo_change = 1.0

# Define a callback function to process audio blocks in real-time.
def tempo_callback(indata, frames, time, status):
    global tempo_change

    # Stretch the audio to change the tempo.without changing the pitch.
    outdata = indata.copy().time_stretch(tempo_change)
    return outdata, pyaudio.paContinue

# Play the audio with the callback function.
_play_with_sounddevice(sound, tempo_callback=tempo_callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

this code works for my problem

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

# Open the wave file
song = wave.open("myMusic.wav", "rb")

# Instantiate PyAudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# Define initial playback speed
speed = 1.0


# Define callback function to stream the song
def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    global speed

    # Read in more or fewer frames based on speed
    frames_to_read = int(frame_count * speed)
    data = song.readframes(frames_to_read)

    # If end of song is reached, stop playback
    if data == b'':
        return None, pyaudio.paComplete

    # If speed is less than 1, add zeros to slow down playback
    if speed < 1.0:
        data += b'\x00' * (frame_count - frames_to_read) * song.getsampwidth() * song.getnchannels()

    return data, pyaudio.paContinue


# Open a stream and start playing the song
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(song.getsampwidth()),
                channels=song.getnchannels(),
                rate=song.getframerate(),
                output=True,
                stream_callback=callback)

stream.start_stream()

# Allow user to input speed changes during playback
while stream.is_active():
    try:
        # Read user input
        speed_input = input("Enter speed (1.0 = normal speed): ")
        # Convert input to float
        speed = float(speed_input)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # If user interrupts with Ctrl+C, stop playback
        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        song.close()
        p.terminate()
        sys.exit()

# Stop and close the stream and PyAudio
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
song.close()
p.terminate()
```